# Why does this normal map look weird when I use it?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv, shaders

I'm not really sure how to explain my problem, but basically what is happening is when I use the normal map to this model it makes the arms, hands, and feet look funky and weird.

[image: Broken normal on mesh]

I've tried different things like flipping the Normals n' such but it still looks weird or only fixes a specific area and makes other areas look wonky.

Comment: This could be an issue with the texture itself, with UV unwrapping, with material settings, with the geometry etc. Can you share the blend file? Or at least some more details, like the material setup, the texture, geometry, UV map...

Comment: Here's the link to the blend file with the normal maps and whatnot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WzB_JWiDCEFxoObC__7TU7TiaRYl86-B/view

Answer (score 1):

Looks very much like what you get when you don't set the normal map image texture node to "Non-Color"

[image: non-color setting screenshot]

Comment: I have non-color on. Ill share the model with the node setup in a little bit

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have seen things like this occur when there are duplicated vertices. My fix is to select all vertices in the area and go to *Mesh > Merge > By Distance*. A pop-up window in the bottom left will allow you to change the distance to merge vertices.

Comment: I dont think this is the problem. The vertices are fine. I have left a blend file with the model, textures, and normals

Comment: I did some messing around with the file and the way UV was applied was slightly off. I fixed the error by changing the Normal Map node setting to Object Space (as seen here: https://i.imgur.com/c2prsWi.png).